# MVC Multi tenant loads other tenant data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, multi-tenant

I am building a multi tenant application using ASP.NET MVC. Now, noticed a bug but at completely random intervals, sometimes data from the wrong tenant is fetched for another tenant.

So for instance, Tenant1 logs in, but they see information from Tenant2. I am using same database from all the tenants but with TenantId.

I boot application from Global > Application_AcquireRequestState as given below:

```
namespace MultiTenantV1
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        public static OrganizationGlobal Tenant;

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            UnityWebActivator.Start();
        }

        void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // boot application
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext context = app.Context;

            // dependency runner
            Tenant = new Tenant().Fetch(context.Request.Url);

            // third party api calls
            var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            if (session != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CountryCode"] as string))
                {
                    string isDevelopmentMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["developmentmode"];
                    if (isDevelopmentMode == "false")
                    {
                        // api call to get country
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // defaults
                    }
                }

                Tenant.CountryCode = Session["CountryCode"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the entire application I use 'Tenant' object as starting point and use this to query database for further data. I noticed, sometimes a tenant sees another tenant name (not sure if other other data is also visible same way).

I'm initializing 'Tenant' based on HttpContext.Request.Url. So there is no way to load other tenant data.

Can anyone see anything in the above code, or in my use of HttpContext.Request.Url that could result in the wrong tenant being extracted for any specific request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request will override the static Tenant object, therefore on concurrent requests, the wrong tenant will be used.

The key is to store tenant per request, for example in the `HttpContext.Current`. I usually use a tenancy resolver, which contains code like this:

```
    public string CurrentId {
        get {
            return (string)HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentTenantId"];
        }
        set {
            string val = value != null ? value.ToLower() : null;
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("CurrentTenantId")) {
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("CurrentTenantId", val);
            } else {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentTenantId"] = val;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the `Application_AcquireRequestState` I set the `CurrentId` based on the url.

The tenancyresolver is then used in the classes that need to know the tenant, by getting the `CurrentId`.

Comment: "the key is to store tenant per request" this was sufficient clue to resolve the issue. thanks @jeroen K

Comment: @jeroen K, where do you place the CurrentId property so that it can be accessed in the controllers?

Comment: @Picflight I have a class called TenancyResolver (which has the CurrentId property), which I use in controllers. It is injected through the DI framework (simpleinjector), where it is registered  as a per request singleton.